# SQL script to create insert script

Tags: sql, postgresql

A bit of a vague title, I will explain.

I am writing an SQL script to create an insert statement for each row of a table in my database, purely to be able to apply that data back to another database.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES ('||ID||','''||name||''','''||description||''');' FROM products
```

And it works great, outputting this:

```
INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (1,'Lorem','Ipsum');
INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (2,'Lorem','Ipsum');
INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (3,'Lorem','Ipsum');
INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (4,'Lorem','Ipsum');
```

The problem is if one of the fields is empty that row will fail to produce an update script, in the output file the line is just blank. Obviously as there are 20+ fields, some optional this means that hardly any of my scripts are generated.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of NULL fields you can do something like

```
Select COALESCE(Name, '') from...
```

The coalesce function returns the first nonnull value in the list.

For truly blank fields (empty nvarchar for instance) I believe your script above will work.

Comment: I'd like to warn you that this is unsafe from SQL injections. A single apostrophe in one column will mess up your resulting SQL, or might be exploitable by an attacker to run arbitrary queries in your database.

Comment: This also won't generate the same exact rows. The coalesce as above will end up inserting empty string values where it should be inserting NULL values.

Comment: Just use `... || COALESCE(column, 'NULL') || ...` instead.

Answer (score 13):

```
pg_dump -a -U user1 -t products -f products.copy database1
```

and then:

```
psql -U user2 -d database2 -f products.copy
```

and you're done. It's also safer and faster.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `quote_nullable()` function new in PostgreSQL 8.4. In addition to permitting NULL values, it retains your data types and protects you from Bobby Tables (SQL injections):

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (' ||
quote_nullable(ID) || ',' || quote_nullable(name) || ',' ||
quote_nullable(description) || ');' FROM products;
```

In older versions, you get the same behavior with `coalesce()` and `quote_literal()`:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO products (id,name,description) VALUES (' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(ID), 'null') || ',' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(name), 'null') || ',' ||
coalesce(quote_literal(description), 'null') || ',' ||
');' FROM products;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, but I get an error that the function quote_nullable doesn't exist. Despite this Chris Clarks solution has worked. Again, many thanks.

Comment: D'oh, `quote_nullable()` is new in PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python script based on @intgr answer to construct the select statement.
It takes comma separated list of columns from stdin (use -).

I wanted to use [sqlparse](http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/) but I couldn't understand how to use that lib.

```
import fileinput

names = ' '.join(fileinput.input())

ns = [x.strip() for x in names.split(',')]
quoted = ['quote_nullable(' + x + ')' for x in ns]
insert = "SELECT  'INSERT INTO <TABLE> ( " + (', ').join(ns) + " ) VALUES(' || " + (" || ',' || ").join(quoted)  + " || ');' FROM <TABLE>"
print insert
```

A gist of the script is here: https://gist.github.com/2568047