# In postgres is possible to dynamically build a INSERT script from a table?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, bulkinsert

Similar to [SQL script to create insert script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820650/sql-script-to-create-insert-script), I need to generate a list of INSERT from a table to load onto another database (sqlite), like the dump command. I do this for sync purposes.

I have limitations because this will run on a cloud server without acces to the filesystem, so I need to do this in the DB (I can do this in the app server, I'm asking if is possible to do this in the DB directly).

In the app server, I load a datatable, walk his fieldnames and datatypes and build a insert... I wonder if exist a way to do the same in the DB...

Comment: Can you explain (1) why INSERTs and (2) why in the DB - how are you planning to get this information into sqlite without going through your app server? You can, but if you knew how to you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: 1) Because are for populate only 2)I can do it in the appserver, it do a lot of other stuff before return back a full sqlite db, but wonder if can do it in the DB (the DB server are more powerful than my app server)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure whether that helps, but you can use simple ETL tool like 'Pentaho Kettle'. I used it once for a similar function and it did not take me more than 10 min. You can also schedule the jobs. I am not sure whether it is supported in database level.

Thanks,
Shankar